# relation between size of types and their range of values?

Tags: c++, types, floating-point, byte

In c++ or any other language, what is the relation between the size of types and the range of values they take? 
E.g.- char has 1 byte size that means no. Of values it can store is 2^8.  So why can it take values ranging from -128 to 127 only and why not larger values. 
Is it related to bit pattern? 
Or am I misunderstanding this thing. I am new to programming and i grasp the concepts fast but m stuck here in this concept!! 
Please explain this in relation to floating point types too!! Thanks in advance

Comment: -128 to 127 **is** 2^8 values!

Comment: `2^8` is 256, so a single byte can store value 0 to 255, or -128 to 127 if you consider them signed. Both ranges contain 256 different values. If you need larger values you can use more bytes.

Comment: *Any other language*? Python has practically unbound integer types, does that answer your question?

Comment: See the explanation of [two's complement binary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and [IEEE 754 floating point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Answer (score 4):

Start with the basic idea of the number of states. A bit has two states - `0` and `1`. Two bits have four possible states: `00`, `01`, `10`, and `11`. For three bits the number of states is eight:

```
000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
```

The pattern should emerge by now: adding an extra bit doubles the number of states that a group of bits can take. This is easy to see: if the number of states of `k` bits is `N`, then for `k+1` bits there's `N` states for when the added bit is `0` and `N` more states for when it is `1`, or `N+N` altogether. Hence, `k` bits can have 2<sup>k</sup> states.

Bytes are groups of 8 bits, so the number of states a byte could have is 2<sup>k</sup>, which is 256. If you use a byte to represent an unsigned value, its range would be 0..255, inclusive. For signed values one bit is taken to represent the sign. In [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) the value range becomes -128..127. Negative values allow one extra value, because non-negative part of the range includes zero, while negative part of the range does not have a zero.

Answer (score 3):

Its easy, variable of datatype has `2^(sizeof(datatype) * CHAR_BIT)` values. Now it depends if this datatype is `signed` or `unsigned`.

`signed` has `0 .. ((2^(sizeof(datatype) * CHAR_BIT))-1)` values.

`unsigned` has `-((2^(sizeof(datatype) * CHAR_BIT))/2) .. +((2^(sizeof(datatype) * CHAR_BIT)/2)-1)` values.

---

**char** datatype

`2^8` is `256`

where

`-128..127` has `256` values

for `signed char` and `unsigned char` has range

`0..255`, still `256` values.

---

Byte is sequence of 8 bits.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 2^7 2^6 2^5 2^4 2^3 2^2 2^1 2^0
```

The highest bit (in little bit endian) indicates whether value is `0 - positive` or `1 - negative`, the rest of bits are for value.

Then you have

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |    < Max positive number
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 2^7 2^6 2^5 2^4 2^3 2^2 2^1 2^0
```

and

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |    < Max negative number
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 2^7 2^6 2^5 2^4 2^3 2^2 2^1 2^0
```

Zero's becouse numbers are usually represented in [two's complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Convertion from two's complement is following

```
1. Invert all bits -> |0|1|1|1|1|1|1|1| ->  127
2. Add 1           -> |1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0| ->  128
3. Change sign     ->                   -> -128
```